# Where on the disk does WebClient's cache reside?

Tags: .net, caching

What's the path on disk used by `System.Net.WebClient` (i.e. `WebRequest`) etc. to cache received files?

Comment: Same place as IE's, I presume.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for your comment, leppie, you are right. The reason I did not find it by browsing was that the directory is hidden, but the place (Windows 7) is:

> C:\Users\foo\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files

Just had to tell Explorer to stop <strike>treating me like a child</strike> hiding system files.